# Having a selected button on a menubar with a mother style

Tags: html, css, laravel

Im using laravel so I have a 'layout' or mother style with every page. I have a design where when im on a selected page the button is highlighted when on that page, however I cant think of anyway of doing that with one single mother style without having all the menus on each page, making the mother style useless. Any solutions?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a class="green" href="{{URL::route('admin-manage-stock')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag" aria-hidden="true"></span> Stock</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="{{URL::route('admin-manage-portfolio')}}" class="orng"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></span> Portfolio</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="{{URL::route('admin-manage-gallery')}}" class="purpl"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can see one of the Li's are active, making it highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use named routes you can achieve this pretty easily by checking if the current route is the one, the link belongs to

```
Route::currentRouteNamed('admin-manage-stock')
```

would return true if the first link should be active.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li role="presentation" @if(Route::currentRouteNamed('admin-manage-stock')) class="active" @endif>
        <a class="green" href="{{URL::route('admin-manage-stock')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag" aria-hidden="true"></span> Stock</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" @if(Route::currentRouteNamed('admin-manage-portfolio')) class="active" @endif>
        <a href="{{URL::route('admin-manage-portfolio')}}" class="orng"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></span> Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" @if(Route::currentRouteNamed('admin-manage-gallery')) class="active" @endif>
        <a href="{{URL::route('admin-manage-gallery')}}" class="purpl"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> Gallery</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```